# Make small changes to multiple functions without affecting cell reference

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

What is the best way to change ">" to ">=" in 100+ formulas such as:

```
=IF(INDEX($B$2:$B$46,MATCH(A3,$D$2:$D$46,0))**>**$A$2),"1","0")

=IF(INDEX($B$2:$B$46,MATCH(A3,$D$2:$D$46,0))**>**$B$2),"1","0")

=IF(INDEX($B$2:$B$46,MATCH(A3,$D$2:$D$46,0))**>**$C$2),"1","0")
```

Would I need some VBA code?

Comment: A simple Find/Replace should work, make sure you are looking in the formulas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest one more idea if you are not comfortable doing the find and replace in excel.

- Press the key combination Ctrl+`  (BackQuote symbol)
- Now you will have all the formulas visible in the cells.
- Copy the range or columns in which you need to modify the formula
- Paste it in a .txt file and then do the find and replace
- Once it is done copy all the formula and paste it back to the same range.
- Press Ctrl+` again and now you have got all the formulas changed as per your need

As long suggested, take a backup of your worksheet before you do these modifications

Answer (score 0):

As Scott_Craner stated, a simple Find/Replace should work.

1. Save a version of your data in case you misjudged where the search subject is in your data.
2. Highlight the cells with the formulas you wish to change.
3. Press `Ctrl` and the `F` keys (or click on "Find&Select" in the Home tab in the "Editing" group and select `Replace` from the drop-down)
4. In the Find and Replace dialog box, make sure you are on the Replace tab.
5. In the "Find what:" box, type ">" without quotes (note, if there are other > symbols in some formulas, you can distinguish these with some repetitive text before and after)
6. In the "Replace with:" box, type "<" without quotes (note, if you included other text to specify certain instances of ">", make sure you include all the text that should also be replaced)
7. Hit the "Replace All" button.

Your spreadsheet formulas should now be as you'd like them. If they're not, thank goodness you saved another version first. Find/Replace is very powerful, so make sure to limit the scope by selecting the cells you want searched and being sure that Excel will find only those data you wish to change.

If you are interested in VBA, you could use it here. But Excel already has a powerful, user-friendly tool at your disposal.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much everyone!